# How to make functions that draw lines in a for loop(tkinter 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My problem is, that when I use :

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x850")

cans=Canvas(root,height=500,width=600)

a=Scale(root,from_=0,to=600)
b=Scale(root,from_=0,to=500)
c=Scale(root,from_=0,to=600)

for i in range(0,50):
    cans.create_line(i,0,0,i)  #< the loop that i am talking about

cans.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

what tkinter does, is that it waits till the lines are drawn(till the loop repeats itself 50 times) and only then display the app.

What i am trying to do with this loop, is to make tkinter draw lines in real time while the app is displayed. 
 Can someone give me an alternative method to do this, or tell me what is  wrong with the code?

UPDATE: Tkinter does not let any loops run with its mainloop(), i really hope theres an alternative to this.

Comment: Please write an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want help.

Comment: Done. Really sorry for the mess, i completly forgot about the rest of the code really being a key to this ! I guess i lost my head when i posted this.

Comment: You can use subprocesses and draw the lines all at the same time, that is quicker and easy to adapt if you need to do something similar. Additionaly you can create the canvas and **then** add the lines with the subprocesses

Comment: My problem is i DO NOT want to draw the lines at the same time. I wan't them to be drawn on the app(while it is running) in real time one after another with delay. Is there any wayto do so? Also, i know little about the subprocesses module, but still don't see how that could have helped me at all(there's probably a lot that i don't get about it, i just know the concept of it, if the anwser is simple engouh, you can try to explain it to me in a fool proof way if you bother).

Comment: @h_e_u_r_e_k_a: subprocesses are most definitely not the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In tk(inter), live looping is done with root.after.  There are multiple examples on SO that you can find by searching `[tkinter] root.after`.  The below is a version for your code, reduced to an MCVE, with the lines spaced out a bit.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

cans=Canvas(root,height=500,width=600)
cans.pack()

delay = 200  # milliseconds
def draw_line(i=0):
    if i <= 150:
        cans.create_line(i,0,0,i)
        root.after(delay, draw_line, i+3)

draw_line()       
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: One last question : How to make this interactive ? Simply making the function the command of a button does not work, should i make a seperate question about this ?

Comment: You question puzzles me because your previous question with the same title was about interactive input with Scales.  In any case, I strongly recommend that you experiment in IDLE.  Comment out `root.mainloop` so you can experiment with and interact with the gui after running the code.  Read the online resources listed in the docs.  Try out solutions to other tkinter question on SO.  Then ask a new question after you have written new code and tried to fix it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

insert code 
 `root.update()` after each  `cans.create_line(i,0,0,i)`

it will update any changes at real time it worked for me

Example

```
for i in range(0,50):
    cans.create_line(i,0,0,i)
    root.update()
```